# How to auto-indent PHP in NetBeans on OS X?

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, netbeans-7

How do I auto indent my PHP code in Netbeans 7.2.1 in Mac OS X? Which short cuts options should I use when auto-indenting my code?

Comment: Do you mean you want to press a button and have a whole file reformatted, or do you mean indent-as-you-type?

Answer (score 8):

Try : `Shift + Contrl + F` to auto-indent your code

Or Source → Format (In parameters)

Maybe , You will have to select all the text before (Contrl + A)

Answer (score 1):

If that did not work try `ALT + Shift + F` which works in my installation of netbeans.

Otherwise the aformentioned Source -> Format works.